# autocomplete and live?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following script which works as long as #txtAllowSearch is flat html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtAllowSearch").autocomplete({
        source: "test_array.aspx",
        delay: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtAllowSearch").val(ui.item.value); // display the selected text
            $("#txtAllowSearchID").val(ui.item.id); // save selected id to hidden input
        }
    });
});
```

This stops working as soon as #txtAllowSearch is dynamically created by javascript/jquery.

Do I need to use jqueries live to get this to work?

Comment: probably yes if #txtAllowSearch is been dynamically created and inserted i DOM

Comment: or just bind that function after the #txtAllowSearch is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuerys `.live()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/live/)</sup> // `.delegate()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)</sup> only catch **events**. In your case (applying a plugin method on an element), you would need to call `.autocomplete()` each time after the element was inserted into the DOM, or use the excellent `.livequery`<sup>[help](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)</sup> plugin.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.live is now deprecated.

To achieve this you should now us $(document).on.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("focus.autocomplete", "#txtAllowSearch", function() {
        source: "test_array.aspx",
        delay: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtAllowSearch").val(ui.item.value); // display the selected text
            $("#txtAllowSearchID").val(ui.item.id); // save selected id to hidden input
        }
    });
});
```

For more information see the jQuery API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/